# Spring LDAP 'bad credentials' (failed to bind)

Tags: spring, spring-security, jasperserver

I'm using Spring Security (well, jasper reports server, that uses Spring security) to connect to a Microsoft AD. But I'm getting a 'bad credentials' in my log but I know the credentials are fine and on my same machine I can use JXplorer to connect to my AD and can use another program to login using this account. The log shows it's connecting, but failing:

```
Authentication attempt using com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSLdapAuthenticationProvider
Processing authentication request for user: pharmacy
Searching for user 'pharmacy', with user search [ searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={0})', searchBase: 'OU=Users', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://10.17.188.4:389/dc=harris,dc=local'
Searching for entry under DN 'dc=harris,dc=local', base = 'ou=Users', filter = '(sAMAccountName={0})'
Found DN: cn=pharmacy,ou=Users
Attempting to bind as cn=pharmacy,ou=Users,dc=harris,dc=local
Removing pooling flag for user cn=pharmacy,ou=Users,dc=harris,dc=local
Failed to bind as cn=pharmacy,ou=Users: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 532, v1772
Bad credentials
```

In my AD the user is as follows:

distinguished name: CN=pharmacy,OU=Users,DC=harris,DC=local

My configuration is as follows:

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg>
                <ref local="ldapContextSource"/>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="userSearch">
                <ref local="userSearch" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="ldapContextSource" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://10.17.188.4:389/DC=harris,DC=local"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=ldadmin,OU=Users,DC=harris,DC=local"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxxx"/>
    <property name="referral" value="follow" />
</bean>


<bean id="userSearch"
      class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSFilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value>OU=Users</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <value>(sAMAccountName={0})</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2">
        <ref local="ldapContextSource" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="searchSubtree">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I see so many different permutations of config on the internet it's hard to know which to follow. I did have a DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator constructor for the group with the authentication provider but that didn't work either.

Can anyone help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been a VPN issue. The above is fine :)

Leaving in case anyone needs to get Microsoft AD working with Jasper/Spring.